# Javascript Scroll not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a smooth scroll to another section from my navigation.

The following is the javascript function im using 
:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function goToByScroll(id){
      // Reove "link" from the ID
              // Scroll
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
                'slow');
        }

        $("#nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
              // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
            e.preventDefault(); 
              // Call the scroll function
            goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));           
        });
    </script>
```

My HTML is as following :

```
<div class="module-group right">
     <div class="module left" id="nav">
          <ul class="menu">
                <li class="">
                     <a href="#">
                      Home
                      </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="">
                      <a id="about" href="#">
                      About Us
                      </a>
                 </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

My section is as below :

```
 <section id="about">
            <div class="container" id="">
                <div class="row" id="">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <h4 class="uppercase mb80">About Us</h4>
                        <div class="tabbed-content button-tabs vertical">
                            <ul class="tabs">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <div class="tab-title">
                                        <span>Introduction</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <h5 class="uppercase">Let's Talk about</h5>
                                        <hr>
                                        <p align="justify">

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tab-title">
                                        <span>History</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <h5 class="uppercase">Our footprints on the sands of time..</h5>
                                        <hr>
                                        <p align="justify">

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tab-title">
                                        <span>Mission</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <h5 class="uppercase">Our Mission</h5>
                                        <hr>
                                        <p align="justify">

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="tab-title">
                                        <span>Vision</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <h5 class="uppercase">Our Vision</h5>
                                        <hr>
                                        <p align="justify">

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--end of button tabs-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end of row-->
            </div>
            <!--end of container-->
        </section>
```

I am facing problems calling the jquery function. I looked up on other questions asked and tried implementing an answer previously given, however it doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: You can not have two elements with the same id.

Comment: The scrolling is not working

Comment: @epascarello I tried changing the id name and then removing that extra element from that id in jquery. Still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your nav link to `<a href="about">About Us</a>`.

Then change the function call to `goToByScroll($(this).attr("href"));`

Comment: It works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/up14xx5b/ Make sure you've included jQuery *before* your own script, and make sure your script is at the bottom of `</body>` (or wrap it in `$(document).ready()`)

Comment: I changed the jquery reference to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

im getting an uncaught reference error $ is not defined

Comment: Here's a version using 1.9.1: https://jsfiddle.net/up14xx5b/1/ Again, it works perfectly fine. The error you mentioned indicates your script is run *before* jQuery is included, which I already told you is the wrong order of the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two elements with the same id. Use the href like it was intended.

```
<a href="#about"> About Us </a>
```

and when you read the hsah of the clicked anchor

```
    function goToByScroll(id){
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top},
            'slow');
    }

    $("#nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        goToByScroll(this.hash);           
    });
```

basic example:

```js
function goToByScroll(id) {
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
    },
    'slow');
}

$("#nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  goToByScroll(this.hash);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#about"> About Us </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div style="height:300px;">x</div>
<div style="height:300px;">x</div>
<div id="about" style="height:300px; border: 1px solid black;">ABOUT</div>
<div style="height:300px;">x</div>
```

Comment: This works, but it doesnt scroll, it goes to the section in a flash second

Comment: I am betting you are binding the events before the elements are rendered. You need to either have the script be at the end of the body or use document ready.

Comment: The script is after the body is closed.

Comment: Well is the menu loaded dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Use `href` attribute to store the id you need to scroll to. Also don't forget to wrap javascript in `$(document).ready()` to make sure event handlers are attached after the page is ready.
Here's javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  }

  $("#nav > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

And in HTML:

```
<li class="">
  <a href="#about">
    About Us
  </a>
</li>
```